# JPA connects to a different database instead of the one specified in my persistence.xml

Tags: jpa, configuration, wildfly, datasource

Here's my persistence xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence 
http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="GoodreadsJpa">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>entity.Book</class>
    <class>entity.Review</class>
    <class>entity.UserActionLog</class>
    <class>entity.User</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/goodreads_clone?useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC;" />
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/goodreads_clone?useUnicode=true&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC;"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

As you can see I have provided jdbc url for connecting to the database. However, when I run my application I get the following information.

```
14:31:57,377 INFO  [org.eclipse.persistence.connection] (default task-2) Connected: jdbc:h2:mem:test
User: ROOT
Database: H2  Version: 1.3.173 (2013-07-28)
Driver: H2 JDBC Driver  Version: 1.3.173 (2013-07-28)
```

which states that I connected to jdbc:h2:mem:test and consequently I cannot perform the desired actions.

It makes me think I am connected to a wrong database?Am I missing something? How can I actually connect to the db that I want?

I am using Wildfly 10 and EclipseLink. Not using Maven.

Comment: Application-managed or container-managed em? If the latter, you've probably defined a data source in the server config and that's the one that is getting picked up

Comment: Container managed. I see. I have to modify the standalone.xml in my wildfly server then?

Comment: That would be my guess (most probably that's where the `jdbc:h2:mem:test` is coming from). You should then refer to your datasource using the `persistence-unit.jta-data-source` (or `persistence-unit.non-jta-data-source`) tag in your persistence unit definition. If you need both the MySQL and H2 data sources, you can create multiple persistence units and differentiate between them using `@PersistenceContext(name = "...")`

Comment: @crizzis Yes that worked. Thank you for the solution, if you want you can add an answer and I'll accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using container-managed em, you should define your data source in Wildfly configuration (`standalone.xml`). You should then refer to your datasource using the `persistence-unit.jta-data-source` (or `persistence-unit.non-jta-data-source`) tag in your persistence unit definition.

If you need both the MySQL and H2 data sources, you can create multiple persistence units and differentiate between them using `@PersistenceContext(name = "...")`

Answer (score 1):

1.You need to add mysql driver to Jboss like here : [Can't add mysql driver to jboss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19319171/cant-add-mysql-driver-to-jboss)

or here 
https://synaptiklabs.com/posts/adding-the-mysql-jdbc-driver-into-wildfly/

2. You need add mysql datasource in standalone.xml configuration file like here :
   https://zorq.net/b/2011/07/12/adding-a-mysql-datasource-to-jboss-as-7/

   `<datasource jndi-name="java:/mydb" pool-name="my_pool" enabled="true" jta="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
              <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</connection-url>
              <driver>mysql</driver>
              <security>
                 <user-name>root</user-name>
                 <password>root</password>
              </security>
              <statement>
                 <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                 <share-prepared-statements />
              </statement>
           </datasource>`